# how to manipulate array response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have an array below

```
const sampleResponse = [
    {
      benefitTypeCode: 'HE',
      benefitTypeValue: 'HEALTH',
    },
    {
      benefitTypeCode: 'DE',
      benefitTypeValue: 'DEATH',
    },
  ];
```

how to manipulate array string into our desire string

my goals

```
const sampleResponse = [
    {
      benefitTypeCode: 'HE',
      benefitTypeValue: 'live',
    },
    {
      benefitTypeCode: 'DE',
      benefitTypeValue: 'passed away',
    },
  ];
```

need advise.. sorry im newbie , thanks a lot btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an object. So, you can iterate through it and change the value of your desired key you want to modify. Hope, the below code will be helpful.

```
sampleResponse.forEach((element) => {
  if (element.benefitTypeCode === 'HE') {
    element.benefitTypeValue = 'live'
  } else {
    if (element.benefitTypeCode === 'DE') {
      element.benefitTypeValue = 'passed away'
    }
  }
})
```

console.log(sampleResponse)

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `forEach` to modify the array. This approach frequently lead to hard-to-understand code and are generally to be avoided.

Comment: this one work f ine for me, thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

simply make object for it and use it's index

like this :

```
const dictionary = {
  HEALTH: 'live',
  DEATH: 'passed away',
};

const sampleResponse = [
  {
    benefitTypeCode: 'HE',
    benefitTypeValue: dictionary['HEALTH'],
  },
  {
    benefitTypeCode: 'DE',
    benefitTypeValue: dictionary['DEATH'],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

Create a map with new values

```
const newBenefitTypes = {
  HEALTH: 'live',
  DEATH:  'passed away',
}
```

And convert old array

```
const newResponse = sampleResponse.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  benefitTypeValue: newBenefitTypes[item.benefitTypeValue],
}))
```